# How to declare namespace for Element in Marklogic?

Tags: xml, namespaces, xquery, element, marklogic

I want to declare namespace for an Element. I am trying as below-

```
declare namespace abc="http://marklogic.com/somenamespace";
let $link := "anylink"
let $Content := <content>content</content>
let $result := element abc:data  { 
element headers{},
element root {
  element {"element"}{
            attribute link {$link},
            $Content
          }
     }
}
return $result
```

The output i am getting as-

```
<abc:data xmlns:abc="http://marklogic.com/somenamespace">
<headers>
------
---------
--------
</abc:data>
```

I don't want "abc:" in my data node. i want it like-

```
<data xmlns="http://marklogic.com/somenamespace">
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Why? Do you really want all the child elements of data to be in the same namespace?

Comment: @chrisis Yes, its a complete envelope, "data" is nothing but my "envelope" node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
declare default element namespace "http://marklogic.com/somenamespace";
let $link := "anylink"
let $Content := <content>content</content>
let $result := element data  { 
element headers{},
element root {
element {"element"}{
        attribute link {$link},
        $Content
      }
 }
}
return $result
```

Comment: In situations where you have to deal with multiple namespaces, but you don't want any to have prefixes, you can also construct elements this way: `element { fn:QName($my-ns, "my-elem") } { ... }`.